# Creating an array with operands results in nil members

Tags: lua, lua-table

I just started learning lua and run into a strange problem. The following code...

```
local xx = 100
vertices0 = {xx, xx}
vertices1 = {xx−5, xx-5}
```

results in...

an array containing (100,100) for vertices0 (as expected) *but*
in an array containing (nil, 95)for vertices1.

I really dont understand what is causing the nil to appear. I expected to get an array with (95,95).

I checked the documentation and tried to google the problem. But was not able to solve this problem.

Btw - I'm using love2d but "regular" lua seeems to cause the same behaviour.

Comment: You're using Unicode minus sign character U+2212 instead of ASCII minus sign

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you very much for this hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xx−5` is not using `-` but `−`, lua treats `−` as part of a identifier so `xx−5` is a separate identifier rather than the desired subtraction operation `xx - 5`

```lua
local xx = 100
local xx−5 = 100
vertices0 = {xx, xx}
vertices1 = {xx−5, xx-5}
  
print(vertices1[1])
```

This appears to work in 5.1, but not later version of lua. additionally an issue like this can be seen easier if you place a space around an operator and it's operands, which does tend to be a good style choice for readability.

```lua
vertices1 = {xx − 5, xx - 5}
```

Also if you have syntax highlighting than you can notice the improper char does not get highlighted properly.